# Domain Model architecture project in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-model, anemic-domain-model

Are there any open source projects in ASP.NET MVC that use the Domain Model architecture instead of the Transaction Script (Service Layer) architecture?  I'm looking for more of a project then just small examples.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [CodeCampServer](http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/) or [S#arp Architecture](http://sharparchitecture.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at mine:

http://clientdatasystem.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

and accompanying blog:

http://lucidcoding.blogspot.com/2011/09/software-architecture-how-to-do-it.html

Comment: I like this project, but you are still using a transaction script layer called Service.

Comment: @MikeFlynn Thank you for the compliment, but there is no layer called service (there is no assembly called service) and it does not use the Transaction Script pattern. Why do you think it does?

Comment: Don't you call a service layer from the controller? GetResponse<List<ClientDto>> response = clientService.GetAllClients() as GetResponse<List<ClientDto>>.  There is also a class called ClientService?

Comment: @MikeFlynn You may be refering to the ApplicationLayer - this could interchangeably be called the Service Layer. How does this make it a Transaction script?

Comment: I would read this and look at the diagram. http://charliedigital.com/2009/07/29/domain-models-anemic-domain-models-and-transaction-scripts-oh-my/

Comment: @MikeFlynn The Service/Application Layer is just loads the required entities, calls the business logic on them (just validation in this case, which is contained in the entity) and saves them. BL is contained in entities. This is not a Transaction script.

Comment: Well then I don't need any help because I am already doing this in my project.  Thanks for the insight.